# How to Pass data from Website A to Website B without using querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, query-string

I am currently working a finance based website now as per the requirement when I click a button on Website A it should open Website B in a window with website A's data(I'm using query string for this) and if someone simply copies paste website-B's URL into another browser or tab it should not allow the user to access it. I can't use query string since it exposes the data

Can you please give me a solution

thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use cookies to store the authkey and data on site A and try to fetch it on site B.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi already tried that i doesn't work that way

Answer (score 2):

on site A. 
Create such forms with your parameters

```
<form method="post" target="popup" id="formID" action="https://siteB.com/contoller/action" >
  <input  name="packing_slip" value="35592" />
  <input  name="reference" value="0018439" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On site b 
Add action only for post method.

Comment: Site b is ASP.NET website, not MVCStie A is MVC

Comment: change action url in form.
On site b you can use such form
For site be read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: also you can set form as hidden and submit in js.